# How to modify the priority of a custom GCD queue?

Tags: iphone, ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I've created a GCD queue like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create("com.testcompany.myqueue", NULL);
```

When I dispatch tasks to that queue, it is way slower than simply executing the task on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(q, ^(void) {
    [self performHeavyCalculationAndUpdateUI];
});
```

My suspicion is that the queue has a very low priority by default.
How can I change the priority of this queue? Or is there something else I must do?

Comment: UIKit most definitely did **NOT** become threadsafe in iOS 4. Where on earth did you hear that??

Comment: They said that at WWDC. I'm 60% sure.

Comment: I'm 100% sure they didn't.  It is *never* safe to modify your UI from any thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Parts of UIKit became thread safe (limited).  From the developer notes here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html "Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe."

Comment: @borrrden fair enough, although drawing into a context ≠ modifying the ui

Comment: @DaveDeLong Yes, of course.  I'm just pointing out what OP most likely actually heard (and subsequently misinterpreted) at WWDC.

Comment: It turns out you can change the priority of a serial queue - thanks to Mike Ash for the answer.  For example to make myqueue run at background priority use dispatch_set_target_queue(myqueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're doing UIKit stuff, in your block that's running on the secondary queue, dispatch the UI updates back to the main queue from within the secondary queue via:

```
dispatch_async(q, ^(void) {
    [self performHeavyCalculationAndUpdateUI];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do my ui update
    });
});
```

Just dispatch the few lines that actually update the UI back to the main queue and you'll see it's not a matter of queue priorities, but rather just making sure that UI updates happen in main queue.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I did what you suggested. However, I can't perceive a difference. My code also reads the frame of views and performs calculation based on those measurements. Must read operations be dispatched to the main queue as well?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Going back to my gallery example, my secondary queue is figuring out width of window, creating buttons and images, doing lots of stuff like that, but I just invoked the actual update to the view (in my case, the `addSubview`) to the main queue. If your changing properties of elements are are already in the view, I would think that you'd have to dispatch those updates to the main queue.

Comment: To make sure I dispatched the method call that causes view-related calculations and changes with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});, but I still see a huge slowdown. About 10 times slower than if I would just not use GCD. Is there anything else that can cause GCD to slow down like this?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might want to put NSLog statements in there and see if you see the messages in your console before you see the impact in the UI. (The NSLog statements show up a little slower when done in GCD, but it answers the big question as to whether your secondary queue is actually slow, or whether the UI updates just aren't being reflected immediately.)

Comment: I'll check on that! Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: By the way, we might be approaching the point that a more extensive code sample might help us diagnose what's going on. Thus far the conversation has been in the abstract...

Comment: I figured out why. It was a blocking core animation call! Somehow with GCD it made it even worse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967384/why-is-animatewithdurationdelayoptionsanimationscompletion-blocking-the-ui

Comment: Seriously, guys don't use UIView anything on a background queue. As for something being slower in the background, why don't you time it (can use CACurrentMediaTime() to get a system-clock-based value in seconds).

Answer (score 44):

Dispatch queues don't have a priority you can change.

You can change the *target queue* of your serial queues using the `dispatch_set_target_queue` functions and use the `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH` global queue. This just ensures that it will be scheduled before any other blocks enqueued on the queues with the default or low priority. Once your block starts executing it will not run faster or slower no matter what queue it was scheduled on.

Your problem most likely is the updating of your GUI, see Robert Ryans answer.

Comment: Thank you for addressing the original question, helps those of us finding this without the UI-related issues in our code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the point of asynchronous activities. And @RobertRyan's comment about UI updates not showing up quickly if performed on secondary queues is wrong. All UI updates need to be performed on the main queue. Period.

But back to GCD and the async queue. @Sven is right that you can't change the priority of the dispatch queues. Queues in GCD work in a FIFO (First In First Out) fashion, so the order you queue them up is the order they get performed in. This is part of why using GCD is thread-safe; you're guaranteed you won't run into any issues because of this FIFO queue priority. The second thing to understand is that when you dispatch_async a queue, the OS provides no guarantee of when that queue will be processed. It's a set-it-and-forget it type of process. If you need to know when the queue is done processing, you need to set up a completion block handler (you'll notice many of Apple's Frameworks have begun to implement this) to be notified of that. This is why Apple suggests nesting a dispatch_async call within your first dispatch_async call and requesting the main thread for UI updates. So, your code would look something like this:

```
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    [self performHeavyCalculations];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
        // some UI updates
    });
});
```

Because of how GCD enqueues and dequeues, dispatching your UI updates asyncronously back to the main queue will allow for UI updates to occur without a perceptible delay to the user. If your UI updates depend on the result of performHeavyCalculations, you'll need to set up a completion handler or delegation scheme to notify the main queue of when this is complete so that the updates can occur. If the lag between the calculations and the update is too long, you may need to look into what you're doing in the calculations method that is taking so long.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I agree that you should do UI updates in the main queue. On the point about no UI updates until performHeavyCalculations is done, though, if that method dispatches UI updates back to the main queue, those happen concurrently with the rest of the performHeavyCalculations processing. You don't have to wait for it to complete for the UI updates to start coming through.

Comment: You don't have to wait, no. But you will wait. GCD queues are processed in a FIFO priority.

Comment: Incorrect. UI updates dispatched to the main queue by time-consuming secondary queues do _not_ wait until the completion of the time-consuming job in the second queue. You see the UI updates happening even though the secondary queue is still busy. My current app does precisely that, and it works great. It's actually why I put the time-consuming job in a separate queue in the first place, so I could immediately show the user a UI, but one that updates continuously based the progress of a time-consuming job.

Comment: I read your comment wrong and you're absolutely right. I've edited my answer for correctness.

Comment: @RobertRyan if you look at the code above, yes, it does wait to dispatch the UI update back to the main thread. This is an example "recursive decomposition". The outer block does `performHeavyCalculations`, and upon completion in that queue, it queues the UI update block on the main queue. The UI update block does not happen until `performHeavyCalculations` is complete. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @quellish I agree. My point was that `performHeavyCalculations` _could_ reflect UI updates with more immediate feedback "if that method dispatches UI updates back to the main queue." When I wrote this, there were a flurry of confusing SO discussions elsewhere about the coordination of UI updates and background queues. But you're quite right that, as written, the UI updates aren't getting submitted until after `performHeavyCalculations` is done (assuming it's not doing something weird like submitting tasks asynchronously to yet another queue). I apologize that I wasn't very clear on that point.