# Under which circumstances can GCD have a negative performance impact on old devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm experiencing something weird with GCD.

First I have a method which performs heavy calculations, and then does some UI layout calculation and updates the UI based on the results.

Without GCD the UI freezes for about **0.5 seconds** every time this method is called.

So I went to GCD and did this:

```
// INIT
// stored in ivar (called only once!)
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create("com.testcompany.myqueue", NULL);


// WORK
dispatch_async(q, ^(void) {
    [self performHeavyCalculationAndUpdateUI]; // modifies self.calculationData
});
```

After this change the method takes about **2-5 seconds** until the change appears in the UI.

The work code in `-performHeavyCalculationAndUpdateUI:` running in the serial queue calls some UI modification code on the main queue (the main thread) the way [Robert Ryan suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965018/how-to-modify-the-priority-of-a-custom-gcd-queue):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Read ivars and objects used during calculation in the serial queue (problem?)
    CalculationData *result = self.calculationData;

    // UI updates like [foo addSubview:bar];
});
```

On the main queue I'm also reading some ivars and objects which were used during calculation in the serial background queue. Can this be a problem?

It still takes about 2-5 seconds until something shows up. Far longer than without GCD.

I'm not using GCD anywhere else except here.

Has anyone else experienced this kind of problems with GCD and knows a solution?

**After hours I figured out: [The Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967384/why-is-animatewithdurationdelayoptionsanimationscompletion-blocking-the-ui).**

Comment: Note that my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965018/how-to-modify-the-priority-of-a-custom-gcd-queue) was about modifying the priority of a GCD queue. I thought that might be it but it seems the problem is not related to changing the queue priority. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: I guess your calculations just take their time … GCD keeps your UI thread from locking while you're performing them. I guess the best solution to indicate that something is happen in the background would be an spinning indicator or some text, which informs your user.

Comment: Not really. Without GCD, my calculation takes just about 0.5 seconds. Why should it take so much longer with GCD? I call this method once and do nothing else, and it still takes 2-5 seconds to finish with GCD.

Comment: Mhh, that's strange – sorry for missing the 0.5 second part :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The troubles you are describing do not come from GCD at least not in the code you posted. I made a quick test function to log the times required to switch queues:

```
-(IBAction)beginWork:(id)sender{
    NSTimeInterval buttonPushTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    // Defined as an ivar : dispatch_queue_t q;
    // created as "q = dispatch_queue_create("com.testcompany.myqueue", NULL);" in viewDidLoad
    dispatch_async(q, ^{
        NSTimeInterval backgroundBeginTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
        NSTimeInterval backgroundEndTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSTimeInterval backOnMainThreadTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

            NSLog(@"seconds to start on background thread = %f",backgroundBeginTime-buttonPushTime);
            NSLog(@"seconds to perform in background      = %f",backgroundEndTime-backgroundBeginTime);
            NSLog(@"seconds to get main thread again      = %f",backOnMainThreadTime-backgroundEndTime);
            NSLog(@"total seconds                         = %f",backOnMainThreadTime-buttonPushTime);
        });
    });
}
```

Then I ran this code on my iPod touch 2nd gen (an arguably very old device. iOS 4.2.1). The results were as follows:

```
seconds to start on background thread = 0.001747
seconds to perform in background      = 5.000142
seconds to get main thread again      = 0.000190
total seconds                         = 5.002079
```

The queue switching in this case added less than 2 thousandths of a second to the time. I recommend you add some similar logging to find your delay.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, are you performing `dispatch_queue_create` every time you invoke `performHeavyCalculationAndUpdateUI`? Are you performing this heavy calculation numerous times? If so, you might want to make sure you're creating the queue only once and dispatching to it as needed. (By separating the queue creation/release from what you dispatch will also help you diagnose what's causing the performance issue ... GDC overhead or some problem in `performHeavyCalculationAndUpdateUI`. Finally, are you also performing `dispatch_release` when you're done with the queue?

There's some GCD overhead, but strikes me that judicious use of when you create and release the queue would be prudent and would help in diagnosing the problem, too.

Comment: No, I create the queue once at initialization time and then store it in an ivar for quick reuse. It's created only once. dispatch_release is called in -dealloc but that never happens because it's a singleton object.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the question with more detail.